# cakephp find arrays

Tags: sql, database, cakephp, find

Hi all I keep getting a Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' with `$receiverName`, when I debug `$receiver` I get this ouput

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'receiver_id' => '3',
            'id' => '1'
        ),
        'FieldsInvoice' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'field_id' => '9',
                'invoice_id' => '1',
                'entered_value' => '1000.00'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'receiver_id' => '4',
            'id' => '2'
        ),
        'FieldsInvoice' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'field_id' => '9',
                'invoice_id' => '2',
                'entered_value' => '2000.00'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'receiver_id' => '7',
            'id' => '3'
        ),
        'FieldsInvoice' => array()
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'receiver_id' => '8',
            'id' => '4'
        ),
        'FieldsInvoice' => array()
    ),

    //returns receiver_id from the invoices table where sender_id=current user account

$receiver=$this->Invoice->find('all',array(
        'fields'=>('receiver_id'),'conditions'=>array(
        'sender_id'=>$accounts2)));

    //returns company_name from the accounts tables where receiver_id=account.id
```

what I'm trying to do is grab `receiver_id` from the array, then compare that with `account.id` then print `company_name` but its throwing an issue with the where statement in my `$receiverName` find

```
$receiverName=$this->Account->find('all',array(
        'fields'=>('company_name'),'conditions'=>array(
        'id'=>$receiver)));
```

Comment: Use `'fields' => array('company_name')`

Comment: still  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: what it prints with `debug($accounts2);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are passing array, change you $receiver line to following

```
$receiver=$this->Invoice->field('receiver_id',array('sender_id'=>$accounts2));
```

Comment: when I go to echo $receiverName it just prints out array

Comment: got it working, just needed to create an index in the view, duh

Answer (score -1):

1) Download and install [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/) (it's a MUST for any CakePHP project - seriously)

2) Click on the DebugKit icon in the top right corner to expand it's options

3) Click on the "Sqllog" tab and see where it's showing "Array" instead of the value you want

4) Change the value to be not an array

5) Buy yourself an ice cream or beer or whatever and take the rest of the night off, since your query now works.

---

**PS** - also per the comment, it should be `'fields'=>array('company_name')`, not `'fields'=>('company_name')`

Comment: I get this error at least once a week and solve it exactly as above in 10 seconds time... not sure why -1 vote.  (Pls in future, if you down-vote something, at least comment as to why you think it's not a good answer)